# asp.NET async problems

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asynchronous

I'm trying to use async for the first time and have been struggling with it for some time, I've tried every resource I can find and I just cannot get it to work.  Changing it to a very basic example with task.delay I got it working but with my code base I'm struggling.

Basically I need to parse a large number of sites, and I need it to be relatively quick.  Below is what I have so far, it runs, but it's not asynchronous.  The output shows them all running one after another, I do have the page tag async=true set too.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
Protected Async Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim dsEvents As New EventsObjects
    EventsReader.Website.GetEventList(dsEvents)

    Response.Write("Start processing:" & Now().ToLongTimeString)
    Dim result = Await GetEventSummariesAsync(dsEvents)
    Response.Write(result)
    Response.Write("<br /><br />End processing:" & Now().ToLongTimeString)
End Sub

Private Async Function GetEventSummariesAsync(ByVal dsEvents As EventsObjects) As Task(Of String)
    Dim debugText As String = ""

    Dim eventCount As Integer = dsEvents.EventDetails.Select("Enabled = 1").Count - 1
    Dim taskList(eventCount) As Task(Of String)
    Dim counter As Integer = 0

    For Each eventRow As EventsObjects.EventDetailsRow In dsEvents.EventDetails.Select("Enabled = 1")
        debugText &= "<br /><br />" & eventRow.EventName & " Start Time: " & Now().ToLongTimeString

        'Await GetEventSummaryAsync(eventRow)

        taskList(counter) = GetEventSummaryAsync(eventRow)
        'taskList(counter) = Task.Run(Function()
        '                                 Return asyncGetEventSummary(eventRow)
        '                             End Function)

        counter += 1

        If counter >= 5 Then Exit For
    Next

    For i = 0 To 4 'taskList.Count - 1
        Dim newRow As String = Await taskList(i)
    Next

    Return debugText
End Function

Private Async Function GetEventSummaryAsync(eventRow As EventsObjects.EventDetailsRow) As Task(Of String)
    Dim dsEvents As New EventsObjects

    Dim EventSummary As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = EventsReader.URLContent.EventSummary(eventRow.EventURLName)
    Dim summaryNode = EventSummary.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='results']/tbody/tr")
    If Not summaryNode Is Nothing Then

        For i As Integer = 0 To summaryNode.Count - 1
            Dim summary = summaryNode(i).Elements("td").Select(Function(td) td.InnerText.Trim())

            If dsEvents.EventSummary.Select("EventID = " & eventRow.EventID & " and EventNumber = " & summary(0).ToString).Count = 0 Then
                Dim NewRow As EventsObjects.EventSummaryRow = dsEvents.EventSummary.NewRow()

                NewRow.EventID = eventRow.EventID
                NewRow.EventNumber = summary(0)
                NewRow.EventDate = FormatDate(summary(1))
                NewRow.NumberofRunners = summary(2)

                Return ""
                'asyncDsEvents.EventSummary.Rows.Add(NewRow)

            End If
        Next
    End If

    Return ""
End Function

Private Shared Function FormatDate(DateString As String) As DateTime
    Dim provider As Globalization.CultureInfo = Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    provider = New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-AU")

    Return DateTime.ParseExact(DateString.Split("/")(2) & "-" & DateString.Split("/")(1) & "-" & DateString.Split("/")(0), "yyyy-MM-dd", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
End Function
```

Comment: Your `GetEventSummaryAsync` function does not contain any `Await` statements and therefore will run synchronously (check your compiler warnings - you'll see the compiler telling you exactly what I said above). Your commented out code (`Task.Run(Function() GetEventSummary(eventRow))`) will fix this by using the thread pool to process your event summaries, freeing up the main thread to queue up the next task.

Comment: P.S. Use `Await Task.WhenAll(taskList)` to await parallel tasks' completion.

Comment: In Web Forms you should use RegisterAsyncTask as shown [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45). Also, do not use Response.Write in a Web Forms page as you don't have control over where the content you've written ends up. Use controls.

Comment: Genius, thanks Kirill, I was closer than I thought :)

Comment: You are welcome. Do look into @mason's comment re `RegisterAsyncTask` though (more info here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx)

Comment: I did look into that a while ago but couldn't figure out how to return a value using it, all of this is within a class, above is simplified. I need to return a dataset but using register I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: All `RegisterAsyncTask` does is allow you to replicate `Async Sub` in an ASP.NET-friendly way. Take the entire contents of your `Page_Load` and paste them into a new `Async Function PageLoadAsync() As Task`. Your `Page_Load` can now be reduced to a single line: `RegisterAsyncTask(New PageAsyncTask(AddressOf PageLoadAsync))`.

Comment: Easy, lots of wins today, that's now working too :), thanks again guys.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy I recommend turning that into an answer.